# MYSQL - Ungrouped Counter of Column value Occurence

Tags: mysql

Mysql Table ordered by `key asc`:

```
id | key | value | OCCURENCE_COUNTER
--------------------------------------------------------
 1    a     ...          1
 2    a     ...          2
 3    a     ...          3
 4    b     ...          1
 5    b     ...          2
 6    b     ...          3
 7    c     ...          1
 8    c     ...          2
 9    c     ...          3
```

Column `OCCURENCE_COUNTER` does not exist in table.
I want to make Query, which could tell me about value of `OCCURENCE_COUNTER` for every row:

```
// pseudo-code:
foreach(row) {
    if(isFirstOccurenceOfKey(current_key)) {
        current_OCCURENCE_COUNTER = 1;
    } else {
        current_OCCURENCE_COUNTER = previous_OCCURENCE_COUNTER + 1;
    }
}
```

I want not group `OCCURENCE_CONTER` by `key`. I just want to get ungrouped counter.

In this possible to do in one single query (or with some subqueries)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understand your question correctly. `occurence_conter` is the table you defined in the question.

```
select c.*, 
    ( select count(*) 
        from occurence_conter c1
        where c1.key = c.key
            and c1.id <= c.id ) as OccurenceCounter
from occurence_conter c;
```